# rotate the 3d object with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit, arkit

recently I have been learning ios AR, but I got a problem which took me several days but still can't solve it.

I use the same method as the apple demo to do the rotation, like below code:
[image]
[image]

I used the above method, but there is a big problem, when i rotation the box, The box doesn't spin on its own center point， instead it use its upper left corner as center point to rotate(see below picture). [image]
it is not the only problem, the other problem is after you rotate like 30 degrees, but as long as you move the box, the box will always be back to the original angle when it first time initialized. After struggling several days， it drives me crazy. And I note the annotation of the method of objectRotation [image]
that means I have to return the first child note instead of self, which I did it before. by return the first child node, yes there is no problems which I mentioned above, but the other problem occured，when you rotation the box, only part of box will rotate, see below pic. [image]

Who knows how to solve the problem? Please help.

Comment: can you try this `SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(2*Float.pi), z: 0, duration: TimeInterval(/*some time*/))`

Comment: Hi , thank you :) , I have already figured a way to fix it.